# Can WRITE_ONCE() Macro Function Be Used for list->prev in Older Linux Versions?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, write-once

Why you think the WRITE_ONCE() macro function is used only to 'list->next' but not to 'list->prev' in
older versions of linux?

Would happen if you also adopt WRITE_ONCE() macro function to the 'list-prev'?

linux-6.3.3

```
static inline void INIT_LIST_HEAD(struct list_head *list)
{
    WRITE_ONCE(list->next, list);
    WRITE_ONCE(list->prev, list);
}
```

linux-5.4.2

```
static inline void INIT_LIST_HEAD(struct list_head *list)
{
    WRITE_ONCE(list->next, list);
    list->prev = list;
}
```

I read [memory-barriers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt).txt and thought that using WRITE_ONCE(list->prev, list) instead of list->prev = list would not cause significant issues. However, I would like to hear different opinions on this matter. In the old version of Linux, what potential problems could arise from using WRITE_ONCE(list->prev, list)?

Comment: "what potential problems could arise from using WRITE_ONCE(list->prev, list)?" - The only possible problem is slower code. Not sure what other problems you are expected by replacing assignment with WRITE_ONCE.